# Significance of using Linq Include when loading other table entry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I noticed that when using the read/write action view template in MVC creating a controller based on a model which holds relationships with other tables (or itself, doesn't matter), it automatically implements the Index Action using Include like so:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var table1 = db.Table1.Include(l => l.Parent).Include(l => l.Table2);
        return View(table1.ToList());
    }
```

I thought that this is used so that when the index loads, the view will include all the model fields (excluding ID of course) along with the the foreign fields such as the Parent or Table2 which seemed to make most sense.

However, I deleted the include parts like so:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var table1 = db.Table1;
        return View(table1.ToList());
    }
```

And the Index still loaded the foreign fields (Parent and Table2) as if the Include clause was not needed at all.

My question is, what is the point of using Include in this specific situation (when MVC loads the template) and also, overall?

Comment: This doesnt seem right... you sure you were testing the new code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **Entity Framework**, `Include()` tells EF that those relationships should be included in the query so the proper joins are generated. That means fields from `Parent` and `Table2` will be included in the result with a **single roundtrip** to the server. (This is also known as **eager-loading**)

However if you remove the `Include()` statements, EF will only initially load fields from `Table`. It has however **lazy-loading** enabled by default, so fields from `Parent` and `Table2` are retrieved from the database when you try to access them. This however will result in one **additional roundtrip** to the server per additional relationship.

You can find more information about the options available for loading related entities in [this entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232) of the EF msdn site.

So, if your Index view uses the fields from the 3 tables, the `Include()` approach would require a single roundtrip (with a heavier query) while the lazy-loading approach would require 3 roundtrips.

As a basic rule of thumb, you could use `Include()` when you are certain you will need those fields. Use lazy-loading when only in some cases you need those fields. In any case make sure you check section 8 of [this EF performance guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853), it nicely explains both options and its implications so you can select the best one for your needs.

Hope it helps!